# How to draw google line chart with multiple strings data

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization

I want to display the results of students using a single chart.

There are 4 exam phases in a year and 5 activities in each phase and each activity has grades ranging from **A to G**. 

I'm using google line chart for this purpose.

**Code for Generating the graph**

```
[<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineChart);

        function drawLineChart() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Phase');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Activity 1');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Activity 2');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Activity 3');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Activity 4');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Activity 5');

            data.addRows([
            ['1', 'A','B','C','D','E'],
            ['2', 'E','D','C','B','A'],
            ['3', 'A','B','C','D','E'],
            ['4', 'E','D','C','B','A'],
            ]);

            var options = {
            title: 'Student Result',
            width: 600,
            height: 550,
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },

            vAxis: { ticks: ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']}
            };

            var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));

            chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="line_top_x"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Link to the Output of this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bFvm.jpg)

The axis is null. It is not generating the chart as per data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you check the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#data-format) for a line chart,
only the first column in the data table may be of type `'string'`,
the rest should be `'number'`

in this case, you could convert each grade to a number.
then use object notation to show the grade instead of the number.
using object notation allows you to provide the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)
`{v: 0, f: 'A'}`
the formatted value is displayed by default.

next, if you want to customize the vertical axis, by using `ticks`,
you won't be able to use a *material* chart --> `google.charts.Line`
you will need to use a *classic* chart instead --> `google.visualization.LineChart`

there are several options that are not supported by *material* charts,  including `ticks`
see [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143) for more info.

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var scale = {
    'A': 0,
    'B': 1,
    'C': 2,
    'D': 3,
    'E': 4,
    'F': 5,
    'G': 6
  };

  var grades = [
    ['1','A','B','C','D','E'],
    ['2','E','D','C','B','A'],
    ['3','A','B','C','D','E'],
    ['4','E','D','C','B','A']
  ];

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Phase');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Activity 1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Activity 2');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Activity 3');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Activity 4');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Activity 5');

  grades.forEach(function (activities) {
    var row = [];
    activities.forEach(function (grade, indexGrade) {
      if (indexGrade === 0) {
        row.push(grade);
      } else {
        row.push({
          v: scale[grade],
          f: grade
        });
      }
    });
    data.addRow(row);
  });

  var options = {
    title: 'Student Result',
    width: 600,
    height: 550,
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom'
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [
        {v: 0, f: 'A'},
        {v: 1, f: 'B'},
        {v: 2, f: 'C'},
        {v: 3, f: 'D'},
        {v: 4, f: 'E'},
        {v: 5, f: 'F'},
        {v: 6, f: 'G'}
      ]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="line_top_x"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome! You are genius bro